# Scanning using remote trigger in ScanAPI

Tags: android, socketscan

I am using the call within the API:

```
.setSoftScanTrigger(ISktScanProperty.values.trigger.kSktScanTriggerStart);
```

Why is it firing up the Barcode scanner from ZXing?  I would like to fire a physical scan on the Socket 8ci.  I am successfully doing this in iOS but the Android SDK seems to be the problem.  I would like to confirm if this is the case either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the method name suggests, `setSoftScanTrigger` triggers the "soft scanner" which is ZXing on Android.

That method just calls a method on ScanApiHelper, passing in the soft scanner as the device to be triggered.

```
public void setSoftScanTrigger(char action) {
    _scanApiHelper.postSetTriggerDevice(_softScanDevice, action, _onSetTrigger);
}
```

If you have a reference to the physical device you'd like to trigger, you could trigger it in the same way.

You would need to modify your `SingleEntryApplication`, because it doesn't keep any references to physical scanners, by default. However, you can set and unset your physical device reference in the same place as it sets and unsets the reference to the soft scanner - the `onDeviceArrival` and `onDeviceRemoval` methods.

Comment: Thanks!  Worked to grab a reference to the connected device and pass it in as the first parameter instead of "Soft Scanner" which is the default in the sample.